# Why then is always called with undefined?

Tags: javascript, promise

I have following chain of promises:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  isUserExists(user.username, user.email).then((existResult) => {
    /// already exists
    if (existResult.rows[0].exists == true) {
      reject('Already exists');
    } else {
      return insertCity({
        city_id: user.city_id,
        city_name: user.city_name
      });
    }
  }).then((cityResult) => {
    /// this is one is always called even I didn't called insertCity above
    console.log(cityResult); /// could be undefined if not called
    return insertUser(user); /// I don't want this to be executed
  });
});
```

If user already exists, I call `reject('Already exists')`. But anyway, next `then` is called anyway, which means `insertUser` is called also. I don't want it to happen. I just want to stop everything when `reject` is called at any point. return reject(`Already exists`) does not help. How can I solve the problem? It seems I don't understand core thing of Promises.

Comment: It seems that `isUserExists(user.username, user.email)` already returns a promise, so why have you wrapped it in a promise constructor?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I created constructor to call resolve/reject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of problems in your code:

- You don't need to wrap `isUserExists(user.username, user.email)` in a `Promise` constructor because it already returns a `Promise`.
- Inside the callback function of first `.then()` method, calling `reject()` rejects the newly created `Promise` but it doesn't stops the execution of the callback function of the first `.then()` method until it implicitly returns `undefined` which then leads to the invocation of the second `.then()` block.

#### Solution

You don't need a `Promise` constructor. Once you have determined that user already exists, you could throw an error.

```
return isUserExists(user.username, user.email)
   .then((existResult) => {
       /// already exists
       if (existResult.rows[0].exists == true) {
         throw new Error("already exists");
       }
       
       return insertCity({ city_id: user.city_id, city_name: user.city_name });
   })
   .then((cityResult) => {
       console.log(cityResult);
       return insertUser(user);
   });
```

Make sure to add the `.catch()` block in the calling code to handle the error when the user already exists.

Comment: Shoud  I attach `catch` after `then` in above code or I can just attach catch in caller code once only?

Comment: You could add the `.catch()` block in the function but it is unnecessary. It is better to add the `.catch()` block in the code that calls this function. This way you only have to add the `.catch()` block once.

Comment: @neo  Generally speaking try and avoid catch as much as possible.  A single catch at the root of any async code is usually the best approach, if you do catch maybe to make more sensible error messages etc, don't forget to re-throw in these places.  Of course don't re-throw at your async root code, or you have an unhanded promise rejection.

Answer (score 1):

You have two independant promises.

If `existResult.rows[0].exists == true` then you reject the **outer** promise.

That doesn't effect the **inner** promise, which hasn't been rejected. So it's `then` continues.

---

Don't nest promises.

Throw an exception if you want to trigger a rejection chain from inside a promise chain.

```js
function isUserExists() {
  return Promise.resolve("OK")
}

function getPromise() {
  return isUserExists().then(function() {
    // it exists!
    if (true) {
      throw "User exists.";
    }
  }).then(function() {
    console.log("This won't be called");
  });
}

getPromise().then(function() {
  console.log("Also won't be called");
}).catch(function() {
  console.log("Error here!");
});
```

---

This is still rather messy though. You'd be better off using `await` and `async` syntax:

```
async function example() {
    const existResult = await isUserExists(user.username, user.email);
    if (existResult.rows[0].exists == true) throw "Already exists";
    const cityResult = await insertCity({
        city_id: user.city_id,
        city_name: user.city_name
    });
    console.log(cityResult);
    return insertUser(user);
}
```